# In my mysql result in PHP, can I replace a column with corresponding values from a different table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using PHP to get results from a MySQL table. The mysql_query returns in variable $r. Suppose I am selecting Employee ID, Employee_team and Employee_salary in my original query. Can I replace the Employee ID in $r(or a new variable with rest of the data intact) with corresponding Employee Names which have to be queried from a different table using the Employee ID?

```
$r = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$r)
        error_log("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Yes, you may try an `update-set` query.

Comment: @Sadikhasan The code is hardly useful here. I have added the relevant bit.

Comment: @theghostofc A little more details?

Comment: @user3766332, for that please share your table structure and then explain what you are trying to accomplish and what you have achieved so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Join the 2 tables in 1 query. And select the fields you want.

Comment: The two tables are in different servers

Comment: Maybe you can use linked server

Answer (score 0):

If the database is on other server, create temporary table and query data from another server into it. Then use JOIN with temporary to select data you need.

Comment: Using temporary tables will kill it. More than 300 million entries in the table. Is there no way to do this after querying? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure, you need all 300M rows?

Answer (score 0):

you can join two table and select any field you want from tables

```
select t1.employee_team,t1.employee_salary,t2.employee_name
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id
```

Comment: The tables are on a different server

Comment: So you can use FEDERATED ENGINE